# Purchase same stock twice

Tags: stocks, selling

Have a stock at present time.  Have not sold it.   Want to purchase the same stock again.  When time to sell one of them,  how does the trading company know which one I want to sell?

Comment: In theory it shouldn't matter because each stock should be worth the same. Assuming both are common stock or both are preferred stock.

Comment: For capital gains it is usually FIFO.

Comment: @MichaelC. -- it **does** matter, because it determines how much tax you pay on the sale.

Comment: @PeteBecker In some countries, yes, but not so in others, where average cost basis may be used to compute gains.

Answer (score 2):

> how does the trading company know which one I want to sell?

It doesn't need to know. You just sell one.

From taxation point of view depending on the country / tax jurisdiction, it can be only be FIFO or specific stock.

Answer (score 0):

Investors purchase additional shares all the time. Every investor that adds money to their investments does this every paycheck or every month. Investors do this every time they reinvest dividends, interest or capital gains. They also buy and sell shares when they decide to rebalance their portfolio.

Whether you are investing via a broker, mutual fund or ETF the investment company can handle this issue. You do want to know how they want you to specify which shares you want them to sell. The laws in your country may specify a default procedure, or what needs to be done if you want to use another procedure, or if you are allowed to change once you have specified a procedure.